# How to save a bug report stuck as a .tmp file?

Tags: android, adb, bug-reporting

I have an android phone with bugreports saved on them. One of the bugreports did not finish properly executing and seems to be saved on the phone as `bugreport-bramble-TQ2A.230305.008.C1-2023-04-21-04-47-02-zip.tmp`.

Looking in the bugreports folder using adb shell I can see the following:

```
bugreport-bramble-TQ2A.230305.008.C1-2023-04-21-04-47-02-dumpstate_log-5724.txt
bugreport-bramble-TQ2A.230305.008.C1-2023-04-21-04-47-02-zip.tmp
bugreport-bramble-TQ2A.230305.008.C1-2023-04-21-04-47-02.tmp
bugreport-bramble-TQ2A.230305.008.C1-2023-04-21-04-47-02.zip
```

The zip file when directly pulled saves as 0KB. How can I save this .tmp as a proper bugreport. Please help.. there is nothing about this in their documentation.

I've tried just naming as .zip, but unfortunately it is not that simple